# Multiplying two complex numbers using only three multiplications of real numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

I have problem given below.

> Show how two complex numbers $(a+ib)$ and $(c+id)$ may be multiplied using only three multiplications of real numbers, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. You may use any number of additions and subtractions.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imCHN.png))

Please help me. How to solve this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Gauss.27s_complex_multiplication_algorithm and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexMultiplication.html

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting; apologies if I changed your meaning. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/d8ccb889-d75c-4a2b-acc7-b6c0f8947277/view-source) how I edited your question. [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee . may i know what is the significance behind this property ? why is this separately emphasized ?

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam, all I know is available in the link:)

Comment: Ya . @Prahlad Vaidyanathan gave the solution to my question . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

Answer (score 21):

You are interested in two numbers : $\alpha_1 = ac-bd \text{ and } \alpha_2 = ad+bc$.
You can compute 3 products, viz. $P_1 = ac, P_2 = bd, \text{ and } P_3 = (a+b)(c+d)$.
Then $\alpha_1 = P_1 - P_2, \text{ and } \alpha_2 = P_3 - P_2 - P_1$.

This process is often called Karatsuba multiplication, and is used in algorithm design quite frequently.

Comment: Simply amazing explanation . Are there any other interesting algorithms like karatsuba algorithm en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm . Can you direct me to good sources for such algorithms that improves algorithm design ?

Comment: I am no expert, but there are plenty of books out there for Algorithm design : 1) Sedgewick and Wayne, 2) Kleinberg and Tardos are two that I have looked at.

Comment: If you are interested in other examples of this kind of phenomenon where you can reduce the number of multiplications at the expense of more additions/subtractions, you can also look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm to see a similar trick for matrix multiplication.

Comment: If you define $P_3 = (a - b)(d - c)$, then $a_2 = P_3 - a_1$, which also saves some computation.

Comment: @sukhmel It's wrong .since  $P3 = ad - bd - ac + bc ,P3 - \alpha_1 = ad-2ac+bc$

Comment: @john, you're right, I incorrectly subtracted.

Answer (score 3):

Prahlad Vaidyanathan has already answered on how performing the product between two complex numbers with only three real multiplications. Now the question is: *can we perform the product between two complex numbers with **less** than three real multiplications?*

The answer is **NO** and is provided by **Winograd's theorem** in

```
S. Winograd, "On the number of multiplications required to compute certain functions", Commun. Pure Appl. Math. 23 (1970), 165-179.
```

**The minimum number of multiplications required in the computation of the product between two complex numbers is three**.

Comment: Could you point some link where the proof could be found?